# ubuntu 18.10 - how to install JavaFX with java

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx

I have both openjdk8 and 11 installed. Neither comes with JavaFX.
I installed both openjfx and libopenjfx-java packages, but can't get my app to work.

```
sudo apt list --installed| grep jfx

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libopenjfx-java/cosmic,cosmic,now 11+26-4 all [installed]
libopenjfx-jni/cosmic,now 11+26-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjfx-source/cosmic,cosmic,now 11+26-4 all [installed]
openjfx/cosmic,now 11+26-4 amd64 [installed]
```

Openjfx unpacks to /usr folder

```
dpkg-query -L openjfx
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/openjfx
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/copyright
/usr/share/openjfx
/usr/share/openjfx/lib
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.properties
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.base.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.controls.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.fxml.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.media.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.swing.jar
/usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.web.jar
```

Am I supposed to somewhat copy the libraries to java lib folder? Otherwise it does not compile blabbering not existing `javafx.*` packages

Previously working jar now exits with:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class helloworld.HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

EDIT

I might be one step closer thanks to @José Pereda

```
java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

now throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class impl.org.controlsfx.version.VersionChecker (in unnamed module @0x28658d1c) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo (in module javafx.base) because module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx.runtime to unnamed module @0x28658d1c
    at impl.org.controlsfx.version.VersionChecker.<clinit>(VersionChecker.java:50)
    at org.controlsfx.control.ControlsFXControl.<init>(ControlsFXControl.java:35)
    at org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox.<init>(CheckComboBox.java:113)
    at org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox.<init>(CheckComboBox.java:104)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
```

Comment: See [the docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) on how to get started with JavaFX 11