# error: The JDK you are using does not support JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I am on Ubuntu 19.04. Trying to run a JavaFX project in NetBeans 11.0. I am getting this message error when I want to create a new JavaFX project: `The JDK you are using does not support JavaFX`
I am using JDK 11 and it seems that there is a problem with installing JDK 8 as you can see here: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java 
I also read that JavaFX is out of JDK 11.

Could someone guide me to how I can run my JavaFX project?

Comment: You need to install JavaFX https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075707/ubuntu-18-10-how-to-install-javafx-with-java

Comment: See: [Netbeans 9.0 with JavaFx 11 and JDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533835/netbeans-9-0-with-javafx-11-and-jdk-11)

Comment: @vladwoguer as it's mention in that answer that I have to install JDK 8. it's problematic somehow as I mentioned above.

Comment: @Kashan why not use the open jdk: `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjfx`

Comment: @vladwoguer got this: E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: If you're using Java 11 and JavaFX 11, then forget about Java 8. You need to pull in JavaFX as an external dependency, just like any external dependency. See [Getting Started with JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Comment: I agree with @Slaw, no need to install Java 8 if you want to use Java 11.
If you want to install the JDK 8 anyway `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa` then try to install again.

Comment: True java 8 didn't solve my problem. Now I will try @Slaw solution

Comment: @vladwoguer OP is using Ubuntu 19.04. Ubuntu has removed OpenJDK 8 from its official repositories. Moreover openjdk-r haven't ported JDK for 19.04 yet. **Kashan**: [Cross-posting is discouraged in SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). This question was [posted on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1135289/816190) as well.

Comment: @Kulfy sorry for the cross-posting. Thought it's more specific. Anyway, thanks for the information

Comment: Have you installed netbeans via snap or ubuntu-make or downloaded a zip from its website?

Comment: the problem is am not sure 100%. As far as I remember I installed it using ubnutu software center

Comment: Do you see netbeans if you run `snap list`?

Comment: yes I do. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You should install java-fx-sdk import it as a library, next create a simple java project and create java class with fxml file.